# multiple calls to strdup() with the same lvalue

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, free, strdup

Throughout the programs I inherited from my predecessors, there are functions of the following format:

```
    somefunc(some_type some_parameter, char ** msg)
```

In other words, the last parameter is a `char **`, which is used to return messages.
That is: `somefunc()` will "change" `msg`.
In some cases the changing in question is of the form:

```
    sprintf(txt,"some text. Not fixed but with a format and variables etc");
    LogWar("%s",txt);   //call to some logging function that uses txt
    *msg = strdup(txt);
```

I know that each call to `strdup()` should have a related call to `free()` to release the memory it allocated.

Since that memory is used to return something, it should obviously not be freed at the end of `somefunc()`.

But then where?

If `somefunc()` is called multiple times with the *same* msg, then that pointer will move around, I presume. So the space allocated by the *previous* call will be lost, right?

Somewhere before the end of the program I should certainly `free(*msg)`. (In this case `*msg` is the version that is used as parameter in the calls to `somefunc()`.)
But I think that call would only release the *last* allocated memory, not the memory allocated in *earlier* calls to `somefunc()`, right?

So, am I correct in saying that `somefunc()` should look like this:

```
    sprintf(txt,"some text. Not fixed like here, but actually with variables etc");
    LogWar("%s",txt);   //call to some logging function that uses txt
    free(*msg); //free up the memory that was previously assigned to msg, since we will be re-allocating it immediatly hereafter
    *msg = strdup(txt);
```

So with a `free()` *before* the `strdup()`.

Am I correct?

Comment: Generally when you pass addresses of pointers like for this function, it's normally the callers responsibility to free any allocated resources returned. As a rule of thumb, when you no longer _need_ the memory, then free it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct. Any old pointer returned from `strdup()` must be `free()`d before you overwrite it, or you will leak memory.

I'm sure you where being simple for clarity, but I would of course vote for something like this:

```
const char * set_error(char **msg, const char *text)
{
  free(*msg);
  *msg = strdup(text);
}
```

and then:

```
LogWar("%s",txt);   //call to some logging function that uses txt
set_error(msg, txt);
```

See how I used *encapsulation* to make this pretty important sequence more well-defined, and even named?

Comment: As an alternative, you might consider statically allocating `msg`. In this case, you logging messages could be displayed even in low-memory condition.

Comment: So I replace all their `*msg = strdup(txt);` by your `set_error(msg, txt)`. That should be easy enough to do. Thank you!